# Why does setuptools take longer than pip to install a package?

Tags: python, setuptools

This takes 23 seconds:

```
echo 'awscli' > requirements.txt
python3 -m venv .venv1
source .venv1/bin/activate
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

This takes 3 minutes and 43 seconds:

```
echo 'from setuptools import setup
setup(install_requires=["awscli"])' > setup.py
python3 -m venv .venv2
source .venv2/bin/activate
python setup.py develop
```

Most of the additional time appears to go into `Reading https://pypi.org/simple/awscli/` and `Reading https://pypi.org/simple/botocore/`.

What is happening here?  Why does setuptools take so much more time to install the package than pip does?

Comment: That sounds like you had cached files. I don't think running `setup.py` manually will use pip's cache.

Comment: Seems plausible, but then I would expect `pip --no-cache-dir` to lengthen the time of the first command, which it doesn't.

Comment: First of all, always try `pip install --upgrade setuptools` for speeding up things - the vendored `setuptools` version is usually old. Second, if `pip` is not installed, `setuptools` falls back to `easy_install` for dists downloads. This one uses regular expressions to parse HTML when looking for dist links, while `pip` uses vendored `html5lib`, so it will always be faster when it comes to dist link resolution.